# Why is an ordered vector not always ordered according to "is.ordered" in R?

Tags: r, sorting, categorical-data

I guess that this has to do with levels and factors but I'm unsure what exactly is going on:

```
test <- c(1,4,2,3,7,9,8)
testOrdered <- test[order(test)]
is.ordered(testOrdered)
is.ordered(rev(testOrdered))
```

Both times, the function returns `FALSE`, i.e., none of the vectors is ordered. At first, I expected the function to test whether a given vector is ordered in the sense of 'order', i.e., "sorted". After coming back to the definition of `is.sorted`, I assume that `is.ordered` asks whether the given vector is ordered in the order of its levels. The vector test (as far as I understand it) should not have any levels, right? So, "false" is more or less the right answer, I guess (but NaN would be better?). Can anyone a) help me to understand what is.ordered really does and when it would be true and b) how to test whether a numerical vector is sorted/ordered?

Comment: For b), see `is.unsorted` which is in the See Also section of `?sort`

Answer (score 8):

In R two types of factors exist: **unordered** and **ordered**. In your case you have a simple numeric **vector**, not a factor. Hence, the function `is.ordered` does not apply as you state above.

An unordered factor is what is often called **categorical** data, it does not have a natural order. To represent this in R you can use an **unordered factor**:

```
f <- factor(c(1,3,2,1,3))
f
[1] 1 3 2 1 3
Levels: 1 2 3

is.ordered(f)
[1] FALSE
```

If the factors have a natural ordering, often called **ordinal** or **ordered categorical** data, you can define this in R using an **ordered factor**. Note the `<` sign in the levels of an ordered factor.

```
f <- factor(c(1,3,2,1,3), ordered=TRUE)
f
[1] 1 3 2 1 3
Levels: 1 < 2 < 3

is.ordered(f)
[1] TRUE
```

So, `is.ordered` will distinguish these two types of factors.